Samsung Touchscreen with Raspberry
I have the Samsung SMART Signage DB22D-T LED at home. I would like to connect this screen to my Raspberry and use the touchscreen.
How do I do this?
The connections of the screen:

Raspberry Pi 4, with Raspberry Pi OS “Bookworm” (Debian 12).
Thank you.
Best regards,
Marco

maybe you are failing to understand that the Raspberry Pi is a linux computer ... would you have the same question with a Lenovo or Dell computer?

I was kind of hoping Marco would have reacted by now @jsotola. As I'm thinking he has already read the manual and has tried the answer I posted. Should he respond, I could go into how the Raspberry Pi might think the HID touch screen is a mouse and the differences between relative position verses absolute position devices.

In the Samsung manual found here, it states:

To control the screen of a PC connected to the product by touch input
From the menu screen, select System → Touch Control → Device to
Control → Connected Source Device. In this mode, the OSD menu on the
product can only be controlled by the remote control.

Also, at the OP has pointed out in the comments, a USB connection is necessary between the Raspberry Pi and Samsung monitor to transfer the position information.

Hi @st2000
Thank you very much.
To connect the RPi, I used a USB2.0 cable USB-A to USB-B (in addition to the HDMI cable).
On the screen, I had to make the following settings via the menu: System → Touch Control → Device to Control → Connected Source Device.
I didn't even have to calibrate the touch, even though I rotated the screen.

Great that you got it working! I think many of us just assumed a USB cable was necessary to transfer position information. I see that a USB cable is not even mentioned in the Samsung manual. Since many people read these questions/answers, I'll add your comment to the answer to make it complete.
